# Coming up with a formula 100+100=100%

Tags: functions

I couldn't find the right phrases to google an answer to my question, but I am trying to come up with a formula and I have no idea how to.

So I have a soccer player who has a physical stat of 100 and a happiness stat of 100, which means he is going to perform at 100% of his attributes. If one of the stats or both of them go down to lets say physical is 97 and happiness is 85 he should perform at n%. Not sure what the formula could be... and one more thing happiness should affect his performance less than the physical. So a player with physical of 100 and happiness of 90 will play better than a player with physical of 90 and happiness of 100

Comment: Take a few more cases (maybe 6 or 7), and attempt an interpolation of some kind, maybe via polynomials, or just straight line. Check what happens to a player who has zero physical and zero happiness, for example.

Comment: That's all you know? Then there's pretty much nothing you can say about the function! But there are always two reasonable estimates: One is a linear weighted estimate, since physical matters more than happiness. Something like $0.6 * P + 0.4*H$, where $P$ is the physicality  and $H$ is the happiness. The other option, is to have some kind of an average of each quantity, say on an average $70$ physicality and $70$ happiness is expected, then we standardize this to $50$ performance, and nearby values to $70$ will produce identical performances, for example.

Comment: I will elaborate like this: In the band $60-80$, everybody's performance should be between $40$ and $60$. Then, below $60$ physicality/happiness you can have a linear graph of some kind, and above $80$ phy/happiness, you can have a very slowly increasing graph to $100$ performance.

Comment: Maybe take the product of those stats instead of the sum (equating $x%$ with $\frac{x}{100}$), if you want to add more weight to one factor, just put exponents. So for example if $p$ and $h$ are your physical and happiness stats (between $0$ and $100$), his performance might be given by $$ \frac{n}{100} =\left(\frac{p}{100}\right)^{a} \left(\frac{h}{100}\right)^{b}$$ with exponents $a < b$ to give a higher influence for $p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way would be through a weighted average. Pick weights $w_1$ and $w_2$ between $0$ and $1$ such that $w_1 +w_2 = 1$, for example $w_1 = 0.7$ and $w_2 = 0.3$. Then
$$\text{Performance} = w_1\cdot \text{Physical} + w_2\cdot \text{Happiness}.$$
You can play around with the weights to get something you like. The higher the weight, the higher the corresponding attribute is valued.

This can be extended to any number of attributes, just create weights $w_1, w_2,...,w_n$ then the performance is given by
$$\text{Performance} = w_1\cdot \text{Attribute #1} + w_2\cdot \text{Attribute #2} + ... + w_n\cdot \text{Attribute #n}.$$